# Stop Heroku Dyno from cycling

Tags: heroku, hosting, cycle, dyno

I have a Hobby Dyno that hosts an application in Heroku in which users can upload images.

What I've noticed is the Dyno restarts during his cycle causing all images to be gone.

```
2018-07-27T16:23:09.914767+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Cycling
2018-07-27T16:23:09.915421+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
```

I am aware of solutions that involve a third-party storage or host the app in another platform altogheter.

I am wondering if there is a way to stop a dyno cycle and never make it restart such as is always in the `up` state?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no way to prevent dyno cycling. Heroku does this [automatically at least once per day](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts).

Heroku's entire design is based on [The 12-Factor App](https://12factor.net), which states that your app's processes are [disposable](https://12factor.net/disposability). Heroku accomplishes this (in part) with its [ephemeral file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), which is why you must persist files using an external service.

Comment: Your processes are disposable, but your data isn't. Your database would be hosted somewhere persistent, such as Heroku's own Postgres offering, Amazon RDS, etc.

Comment: What! And they now charge 7 usd per dyno. smh. Thanks for the answer.